# JSFUnit inconsistently getting JSFServerSession

Tags: jsf-2, jboss-arquillian, weblogic12c, jsfunit

We are trying to run JSFUnit with Arquillian on a WebLogic 12c container and are running into a few problems.

First, when we try to use the @InitialPage annotation to inject in the JSFServerSession and JSFClientSession, the JSFServerSession is always returned as null.

Second, we have tried working around the problem by going the legacy route of creating a new JSFSession and then getting the JSFServerSession and JSFClientSession from it.  Once we run a second test we get "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not find HttpSession.  Make sure JSFUnitFilter has run and your test extends org.apache.cactus.ServletTestCase."

It seems very arbitrary because there are times where we will run a test and it passes.  Sometimes the very next time it fails.  Or adding a line that doesn't seem like it should be related, will thrown the "Can not find HttpSession" error.

It seems like it can't handle creating the JSFSession multiple times or there is some timeout on the server that even though the test war is getting undeployed something needs to timeout.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this applies to your problem as well, but I had similar issue with JBoss 7. Usually the issues can be solved by:

- Using `Servlet 3.0` protocol which should include relevant filters to `web.xml`
- If that doesn't help (like in my case), use this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17036005/1667977
- In any case, try to avoid creating the session yourself